# My wordpress based site is publishing the same post twice

Tags: posts

I have no clue how to go about troubleshooting this. To explain, I am seeign two symptoms

1. Any social media autoposter is publishing the same link twice
2. Wordpress is triggering two emails about successfully posting the same artcle.

Would appreaciate any help.

Comment: Same problem here while making a scheduled post with the ios app. Did you ever get this solved?